# Using Timers to create a single timeout frequently

Tags: c#, timer

I'm working with a timeout which is set to occur after a certain elapsed period, after which I would like to get a callback. Right now I am doing this using a `Timer` that when fired disposes of itself.

```
public class Timeouter
{
    public void CreateTimeout(int timeout, Action onTimeout)
    {
        Timer t = null;
        t = new Timer(_ =>
            {
                onTimeout();
                t.Dispose();
            }, new object(), timeout, Timeout.Infinite);    
    }
}
```

I'm a bit concerned regarding the resource use of this timer since it could potentially be called quite frequently and would thus setup a lot of timers to fire just once and dispose of themselves. Considering that the timer is an `IDisposable` it would indicate to me that it indeed uses some sort of expensive resource to accomplish its task.

- Am I worrying too much about the resource usage of the `Timer`, or perhaps the solution is fine as it is?
- Do I have any other options for doing this? Would it be better to have a single timer and fiddling with it's frequency starting and stopping it as necessary in order to accommodate several of these timeouts? Any other potentially more lightweight option to have a task execute *once* after a given period of time has elapsed?

Comment: Just because something is `IDisposable` doesnt' mean it is using an *expensive* resource, just that it is using an unmanaged one potentially (and I can probably point you at IDisposables that actually use no external resources at all).

Comment: Just not sure that why asking it.Is it server/client environment, that you think of many timers setup to be fired at some time? Or if it is standalone why would it setup multiple timers to be fired?

Comment: True. Just that I don't really know what goes on under the hood of the `Timer` makes me a bit wary. I know it doesn't go around and start a thread for each one but as far as resource usage goes I'm not sure at all how expensive it is to use.

Comment: @Furqan in essence it's like this. It's a server that recieves requests to do things. Each request of a certain kind will trigger some work to be done after a certain period has elapsed. It might receive lots of these requests.

Comment: If you really will be using these timeouts so often, reusing single timer is always better idea than creating a new one over and over again...

Comment: I suggest reusing the timer as wasyl has mentioned.  If you're still worried about disposing of the Timer, you could always dispose of it in the Page_Unload method (assuming ASP.NET) or some when you are actually done with all of your timer needs (not ASP.NET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net has 2 or 3 timer classes which are expensive. However the `System.Threading.Timer` class which you're using is a very cheap one. This class do not use kernel resources or put a thread to sleep waiting for timeout. Instead it uses only one thread for all Timer instances, so you can easily have thousands of timers and still get a tiny processor and memory footprint. You must call `Dispose` only because you must notify the system to stop tracking some timer instance, but this do not implies that this is a expensive class/task at all.
Once the timeout is reached this class will schedule the callback to be executed by a `ThreadPool` thread, so it do not start a new thread or something like this.

Comment: So, what you're essentially saying is that the code I'm using right now would be fine from a resource footprint perspective at least? Would it be possible to do the scheduling on the threadpool manually to avoid the entire disposing thing alltogether?

Comment: I guess there is no need to do this because the Timer class basically does exactly that. Destroy a Timer on the other hand is also a simple task, which basically involves removing a callback from a linked list. If you implement this by hand I believe you'll end up with a code very similar to this class implements, with the disadvantage of having to maintain it. Your code already do a good work using this class ;)

Comment: Great. This is pretty much what I was hoping the timer would be doing. Sometimes I spend more time worrying about resource usage than is helpful.

Comment: In fact Timer classes usually are expensive, requiring we, the developers, to create crazy schedule lists. Luckily the .net team take care of it for us...

Answer (score 1):

Though its not an answer, but due to length I added it as answer.

In a server/Client environment, AFAIK using Timers on server is not the best approach, rather if you have thick clients or even thin clients, you should  devise some polling mechanism on client if it wants a certain operation to be performed on the server for itself(Since a client can potentially disconnect after setting up a timer and then reinstantiate and set a timer again an so on, causing your server to be unavailable at sometime in future(a potential DOS attack)),

or else think of a  single timer strategy to deal with all clients, which implements sliding expirations or client specific strategies to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

one other option is to maintain a sorted list of things which will timeout, add them to the list with their expiry time instead of their duration, keep the list sorted by the expiry time and then just pop the first item off the list when it expires.

You will of course need to most of this on a secondary thread and invoke your callbacks. You don't actaully need to keep the thread spinning either, you could set a wait handle on the add method with a timeout set for (a bit less than) the duration until the next timeout is due. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477.aspx) for more information on waiting with a timeout.

I don't know if this would be better than creating lots of timers.

Comment: Well, it certainly is an option. Sleeping is problematic, considering if the thread is sleeping for say a minute and someone adds a timeout that is due in a second. That timeout won't be handled until after a minute given such a solution. Maybe if one would interrupt the thread that is sleeping.

Comment: @Devall That's what the wait handle is for, to wake up the thread when something adds something to the list.

Comment: @Dervall updated to include a link for timout information with wait handles.

Comment: Great, I'll probably give this a shot to see how the usage characteristics works out for this.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a cheap timer that can time *many* intervals is intuitively simple.  You only need **one** timer.  Set it up for the closest due time.  When it ticks, fire the callback or event for every timer that was due.  Then just repeat, looking again through the list of active timers for the next due time.  If a timer changes its interval then just repeat the search again.

Something potentially expensive might happen in the callback.  Best way to deal with that is to run that code on a threadpool thread.

That's extraordinarily frugal use of system resources, just one timer and the cheapest possible threads.  You pay for that with a little overhead whenever a timer's state changes, O(n) complexity to look through the list of active timers, you can make most of it O(log(n)) with a SortedList.  But the Oh is very small.

You can easily write that code yourself.

But you don't have to, System.Timers.Timer **already works that way**.  Don't help.

Comment: Wouldn't the reference contained in the closure prevent the garbage collector from destroying my timer?